# Semaphore or lock with waiting list served in LIFO order

Tags: java, scala, locking, semaphore, lifo

Looking for efficient semaphore or lock with LIFO ordered list of waiting threads to try to minimize cache and page misses in following implementation of [`FixedThreadPoolExecutor`](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/actors/FixedThreadPoolExecutor.scala).

Comment: Have you done some research? If yes, you may have stumbled upon [`BlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html), which has implementations...

Comment: I'm not looking for LIFO structure of user data, instead looking for ways how to park/unpark threads efficiently and maintain list of parked threads in LIFO order.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LIFO datastructure, and make thread priorities change dynamically corresponding to the index position of the datastructure.